# NPM cant find file it thinks is cached (errno -4058 no such file or directory)

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to do npm install with a git directory, i get this every time.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-4622a2ff/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-4622a2ff\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I tried:

- `npm cache clean -f`
- `npm cache verify`
- deleting the whole npm-cache folder in both local and roaming app data
- `npm install npm@latest -g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled node completely, deleted all npm folders in appdata. Reinstalled node. Then it worked enough to give me a different error.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when I tried installing a git dependency with `npm install`. The problem was the git dependency didn't have a package.json file.
Generating a package.json file into the git dependency fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I manually packaged some dependencies like this.

`"@swf/pdfjs": "file:lib/swf-pdfjs-2.14.305c.tgz"`

My mistake was in the `package` folder of the archived file, there was no `package.json` file for the dependency and after I repackaged it correctly it worked fine again.